# Changing object attribute within a custom class (Python)

Tags: python, oop, attributes, tkinter

I am trying to change a python variable by calling a method on its class. My actual code is a lot more complicated than the below, but the below demonstrates the problem. I understand that self means the instance of the class in question, so I thought simply going self.val = 5 or whatever would work. But it's not.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious. I've just been getting into classes in Python and it all seemed fairly straightforward and how I remembered OOP from many years ago, but after a couple of hours of trying different things and googling all manner of phrases I'm still stuck. I'm using Python 2.7.

```
from Tkinter import *

class mylistbox(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Listbox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.val = 2    # setting val in this instance to 2

    def change(self, newval): #in my real code this method does a lot more
        self.val = newval # this doesn't change val in this instance!
        print "self.val is now " + str(self.val)

def callback(x):
    print x

top = Tk()

listbox = mylistbox(top)
listbox.pack()

b = Button(top, text="change", command = lambda zzz=7: listbox.change(zzz))
b.pack()
b = Button(top, text="answer", command = lambda myval=listbox.val: callback(myval))
b.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

If I click answer, change, answer then the output I get is...

- 2
- self.val is now 7
- 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's changing just fine! The problem isn't anything to do with your class; it's that second lambda that's causing it. Default values in Python are evaluated when a function is created, not when it's called: `myval`'s default is bound to the value of `listbox.val` at the time the lambda is created, and won't change no matter what happens to `listbox`.

If you change that lambda to something like `lambda box=listbox: callback(box.val)` the changes will be visible.

Comment: Thanks! You and unutbu said basically the same thing but I should give the accepted answer to someone, and you answered slightly quicker...

Answer (score 2):

The lambda default value `listbox.val` is evaluated at definition-time. So if you use

```
lambda myval=listbox.val: callback(myval)
```

then `myval`'s default value equals 2 forever.

Instead, you could use

```
b = Button(top, text="answer", 
           command=lambda mybox=listbox: callback(mybox.val))
```

Comment: ARGH! So simple. I thought it was something to do with me calling the attribute of an object as I've been using variables in lambda functions elsewhere and it's been fine. At least my mis-understanding was in lambda functions (which I don't fully understand yet) rather than basic OOP theory (which I theoretically do understand) :) Thanks!